# Use Attributes to add decoration code to property's set/get method

Tags: c#, properties, attributes

I don't know if I am asking the impossible or not, I have tried to see what I could find via Google but perhaps I am not expressing what I am looking for in the right search terms. If it is out there please forgive me!

I was hoping to use a Custom Attribute to execute additional code when the set method of a property is executed.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
public class MyAttribute : System.Attribute{
     AttributedProperty.Get(Property p){
          Console.WriteLine("The value of the Property '{0}' has just been retrieved!", p.Name);
     }
     AttributedProperty.Set(Property p){
          Console.WriteLine("The value of the Property '{0}' has just been set!", p.Name);
     }
}

public class MyClass{
     private string _someProperty;
     [MyAttribute]
     public string SomeProperty{
           get{ return _someProperty;}
           set{ someProperty = value;}
     }

}
```

Rarely is something as simple as pseudo code so I am prepared to do a bit of work, I just need some direction if I could please :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Attribute`s are not suitable for this manner,they just add meta information on your members and you can read them via `Reflection`.
Instead you can use some thing like `Castle.Proxy` to have interceptor on your methods and properties.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Castle.Proxy looks pretty darn powerful. Much appreciated!